# How can I add an object in an object with Local Storage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage

I hope I can explain my problem. What I want to do is to create a new object inside the selected object.

It is like this: When I select an x ​​object, I want to keep the data that I will select from now on in this object.

```
Sample :
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "cars": {
    "car1": "Ford",
    "car2": "BMW",
    "car3": "Fiat"
  }
 }
```

How can I do this with localstrorage? I want that I can create a new object into the first selected object and then the selected data.

When a different name is chosen, then all selected data can be added as objects.

```
// Add mark as read list
function addData(con){
   
    let user_name    = $(con).data('name');
    let age          = $(con).data('age');
    let car1         = $(con).data('car1');
    let car2         = $(con).data('car2');
    let car3         = $(con).data('car3');
 

  // Get bookmarks
  let bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("array_row"));
  // When this object do not exist, create a new array
  if(bookmarks === undefined || bookmarks === null) bookmarks = new Array();
  //console.log(bookmarks);
  bookmarks.push({user_name,age,car1,car2, car3});
  console.log(bookmarks);
  // Save the new bookmark in the local storage
  localStorage.setItem("array_row", JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
  // Update the table which displays the bookmarks
  updateData();


}
```

Comment: You are using `localStorage` `getItem` and `setItem` with `JSON` `parse` and `stringify` correctly.
So, I guess I don't understand your question.

Comment: Think of it this way: I'm choosing a user. And then I specify the cars that belong to this user. I want that When I select the user, I want to list the selected vehicles in the object whose key is the car into the created object.